# How do I detect if the phone loading my website is a feature phone?

Tags: php, feature-detection, mobile-browser

First of all, I know that feature phones aren't that popular anymore but I still want to cater for the users. What I'm asking is to be able to determine if the browser is on a feature phone instead of a smart phone. I have a stripped down version of my website that is specially for feature phone users who normally have slower internet connection.

I need to do the detection from the server side (PHP) since I want to serve them the minimal version from the get-go instead of having them load the heavy page first.

Comment: You have two common options: Browser sniffing or Javascript libraries (eg: jQuery). I am religiously opposed to browser sniffing, but it could work well to sniff out feature phones.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this in server side scripts, but in client side scripts, you can consider devices with less than 320px screen width as feature phone (If you want to serve for smart watches also, then this wont work).

Comment: @kainaw, care to elaborate on the browser sniffing? I believe Facebook is able to switch to the barebones version of the website if it's accessed from a feature phone. Are they using browser sniffing?

Comment: @Manikiran, I don't want to use client-side scripts because as I stated above, the goal is to minimize the bandwidth footprint from the get-go.

Comment: @user400424 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing